# How to get notification when node auto scale happens in GKE

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to get a slack notification or any type of notification when node auto scaler scale nodes in my GKE cluster.

Is there any possible way to implement anything in GCP to get a notification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many depends on what type of `Monitoring` are you using in your cluster.

If you are using 3rd party software like [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/), or [Grafana](https://grafana.com/), on `Market Place` you can find ready images of `Prometheus Alertmanager` or `Prometheus & Grafana` where you can configure many notification options.

If you would like to use `Google Cloud Monitoring` you can specify which `notification channel` you would like to use. Types are mentioned in [Managing notification channels](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) (email, sms, slack, etc).

Please check documentation regarding [Alerting behavior](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth) for more information.

However if you would like to get events, you can check them in `Cloud Logging`. It's well described in [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility).

Comment: thankyou for writing answer but incloud logging event i am using GKE version 1.14 it support from 1.15

Comment: I understand, however I would suggest you to upgrade your cluster to 1.15 as per [R26](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#august_06_2020_r26) it will be upgraded anyway to 1.15. Also GKE 1.14 isn't available for new clusters at the moment.